# Automatically "manually" update windows fully?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows' automatic updates are never fully automatic. It asks you to restart now and you'll find it still like that hours later. Plus, after restarting, it doesn't check for more updates, which is a problem cause nearly every time I have to restart for updates, there are more that just didn't show up.

Is it possible and how can I have a script/usb rubber ducky/whatever, that handles updates as if a person is sitting there?

It would, upon starting, tell windows to update. As soon as all updates are installed, regardless of whether windows actually is asking for a restart, do a restart, and repeat until twice after restarting, windows doesn't have any updates left?

I've tried googling around to see if anyone has made something like this, and I can't seem to find anything, so it probably doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how it would be possible. For a script, it would have to insert itself into autorun, for a rubber ducky, it'd need some way of being more than a fake keyboard.

In summary, I want something to tell Windows to update, as if it was a person hitting "check for updates" and "restart now", so windows can just be given a few hours and be fully up to date.

Comment: If you routinely keep your system updated, it typically only takes Windows Update one reboot, to install updates.  If you want to install updates manually, installing the cumaltive update for the Windows 10 version you have installed, is enough to keep your system updated.  This won't include any other updates release other than cumaltive updates though (those have to be downloaded).

Comment: Here is one way.....http://www.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: @Ramhound the point of this is to deal with computers that haven't been kept routinely up to date. Think taking a computer that's still on Win10 1511 or something like that, and bringing it up to Win10 1903.

Comment: I'll look into and try wsusoffline, and report back when I see if it did what I want, thanks @Moab.